# DynamoDB: Can we append List data with update expression

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

when i am updating some data into database i want, if the `users` (list type) are already there then the new user needs to be appended instead of overwriting.  Is there any option to append to the existing List of users in the database in a single query.

Other option i have is, do a get call first then do append it and update it

Here is Dynamodb data model

```
String :  GUID,
String :  status,
List   :  users
```

please help with your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Use an UpdateExpression of `SET users = list_append(users, :newUser)`

See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html -  scroll down for "Appending Elements To a List"

Comment: but we need to do a get call for that to get the `users` first.

Comment: No you don't. One of the arguments to list_append can be the name of a list attribute